# Too much vertical space after long section title using titlesec

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I'm using `titlesec` to change the style of my section titles. Sometimes, when the title is long, but just short enough to fit on one line, some extra vertical spaces is add. The following MWE illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\normalfont\bfseries}{#1}{.5em}{}

\begin{document}
  \section{This is a short title}
  This is a paragraph.

  \section{This is a purposely long title that shows some odd behavior}
  This is a paragraph.
\end{document}
```

This is rendered as follows:

[image]

Clearly, there is too much space below the second section title. I've played around with `\ignorespaces` and `\ignorespacesafterend`, but can't seem to get rid of the extra space. What to do?

Comment: This is because the book class use '\flushbottom'. Put in the command '\raggedbottom' after \begin{document}.

Comment: @Sveinung: I don't think that is the issue. To be sure, I tried adding `\raggedbottom` after `\begin{document}`, but this does not resolve anything. Also, I tried what happens when I duplicate the sections, and the problem remains: there is more vertical space under sections with long titles than under the other sections.

Comment: I should have written: "It might be because you are using ..." =:-). But Bernhard had a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is above all due to the bad syntax in:

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\normalfont\bfseries}{#1}{.5em}{}
```

You've put #1 at the place reserved for formatting the label. A correct syntax would be, e.g.:

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\normalfont\bfseries}{\arabic{section}.}{.5em}{#1}
```

[image]

Comment: Aaaahhhhh how stupid of me. Thanks so much for pointing that out! I've spent so much time on this :)

Comment: It's not easy to remember all those parameters. And your code couldn't produce any error message on compiling… The label being actually the title, it added a (invisible, of course) space of 0.5 em on next line.

Comment: Yes, I now realize that replacing `.5em` by `0pt` will do the trick too. Thanks!